# ISSUE: Border-Image stretched on safari and not chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, border-image

I'm building a holding website for a client and I've added a border image into my code and it doesnt work on safari. However, it works completely fine on Chrome. I've checked the current posts similar to this issue however I've still not managed to figure out the issue. Any Thoughts?

Thanks!

[issue Screengrab attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcRZA.png)
// [what it should look like screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxqSg.png)

```
#wrapper{
                border-style:solid;
                border: 15px solid;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                -moz-border-image: url(border-brown.png) 33.33% round;
                border-image: url(border-brown.png) 33.33% repeat;
                border-image-repeat: round;
                transition: 0.5s;
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
                }
```